# onAuthStateChanged return unsubscribe, I want to return currentUser

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am in an Angular project (6.0) using firebase (5.2). I am using the function:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged
```

this function returns a firebase.Unsubscribe, which I don't master. I just know to work with Observables, Subjects and Promises.

I would like to use this function as a observable, like, I subscribe to it whenever I get the currentUser back.

So far, I've tried to wrap it a observable:

auth.service.ts

```
  loadUser() {
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(
        currentUser => { return currentUser }
      )
    })
  }
```

and I subscribe whenever I start my angular application:

in ngOnInit:

```
this.authService.loadUser()
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log("response");
      console.log(response);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
```

But the subscription is never triggered. I am not wrapping right the function of Firebase.
1. I don't really understand why they return a firebase.unsubscribe.
2. How can I solve the challenge?

Thanks

Comment: instead of `currentUser => { return currentUser }` try `currentUser => { observer.next(currentUser) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider using the library [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) (I'd really recommend at least trying it out for your application), you can take advantage of injectable services such as [AngularFireAuth](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md) to track authentication state as an observable. Below is example of using AngularFireAuth from angularfire2 to get current user information, check if a user is logged in, and signin/signout

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { User, UserCredential } from '@firebase/auth-types';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...

user: Observable<User>;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
}

getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.user.pipe(take(1));
}

isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.user.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(authState => !!authState)
  );
}

logUser() {
  this.getUser().subscribe(user => console.log(user));
}

login(): Promise<UserCredential> {
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

logout() {
  return this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: oh I see. I'm using the firebase library. I will try to use the angularfire2, if I don't need to change too many things. Could you please tell me the differences? is one better than the other one? or just the angularfire2 is kind of adapted for angular apps?

Comment: @AlbertMunichMar angularfire2 does a lot of the work of transforming firebase authentication, realtime database, storage and other events into observable streams and injectable, testable/mockable services. While you absolutely could manually create observables from the source firebase events, angularfire2 also exposes other utilities for helping to track changes to lists/objects as well as recipes for common data display and manipulation tasks. I'd recommend trying it out, but that's just my personal opinion that it makes things easier when working with firebase. Thanks!