# Finish an observable

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

I am trying to write a resolver that will fetch additional data from my database if a user is logged in via firebase.  I have a service that gets the data, but when i try to get the firebase uid first I can't get the timing of the resolver right:

If I hardcode the uid, it works fine:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthResolver implements Resolve<User> {

    constructor(
        private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private userService: UsersService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<User> {
        return this.userService.getUser("[firebase uid]"); // returns an Observable<User>
    }
}
```

But when I try to get the firebase uid first, the resolver finishes before the initial observable has completed.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<User> {
    this.firebaseAuth.user.subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response.uid);
        this.userService.getUser(response.uid).subscribe(user => {
            console.log(user);
            return user;
        })
    });
    console.log("returning...");
    return;
}
```

In the console:

```
> returning...
(Page I am trying to resolve loads here because the resolver is finished)
> [response.uid]
> [User object from the reoslver]
```

I don't know how to finish the observable before the resolver finishes.

edit: This is my attempt using mergeMap:

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<User> {
    return this.firebaseAuth.user.pipe(
        mergeMap(firebaseUser => this.userService.getUser(firebaseUser.uid))
    );
}
```

This didn't work.  It did return an observable, but not an `Observable<User>`.

Comment: You can use RxJS operators such as switchMap or mergeMap to effectively chain the observables instead of using subscribe(). You want to also return an observable from resolver in this situation.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, but that didn't work, unless I am doing something wrong (likely).  See edit above

Comment: You may need to share your service methods including `getUser()`. Perhaps take a look at the following also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365424/onauthstatechanged-return-unsubscribe-i-want-to-return-currentuser/51365665#51365665

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [flatMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/flatMap) to unwrap the value returned from a call to `getUser()`:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<User> {
    return this.firebaseAuth.user.pipe(
        flatMap({uid} => this.userService.getUser(uid))
    );
```

}

What happens here is that whenever we get a response from FireBase `user` observable we extract his `uid`, fetch the user data and provide that as a value for the resulting observable returned from `resolve` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can return promise and resolve only once you get the desired result :

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any{
const promise=new Promise((resolve,reject))=>{
    this.firebaseAuth.user.pipe(
           catchError((err, caught) => reject(err);)  // here reject if request failed
        ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response.uid);
        this.userService.getUser(response.uid).subscribe(user => {
            console.log(user);
            resolve(user); // Or Resolve wherever required
            return user;
        })
    });
    console.log("returning...");
    return;
});

return promise;
}
```

Comment: The only issue with that approach though is that one definitely has to handle an error case (e.g. Firebase is down or uid was missing in a response, etc).
Otherwise, this promise will never be resolved which will lead to infinite waiting.

Comment: no, in that case catchError and reject(errorResponse), try, it will work (y)

Comment: That is what I meant by "handle an error case".
Without .pipe(catchError(err => reject(err)) a simplest 404 error will yield to infinite wait.
Please, correct your snippet by adding a missing error handling so that the author can see the overall picture.
Thanks.

Comment: yes, indeed i should clarify the author, and handle all scenarios in snippet. Somehow, mistook you as the author in the previous comment